# Can't log on to any site that has Captcha

Tags: captcha

trying to login to my Bandcamp page,captcha is run by google,keeps denying me. Please help. Same with my yahoo mail. Ugh!

Comment: I can't answer your question. Stackexchange uses Goggle reCaptcha to block be from answering. I don't know how it works, but when I input the answer I have written -> post -> captcha -> blocked. OR once in a while it lets me do the captcha, but then stackexchange writes "Oops bot detection failed."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having Tor browser use a new circuit, and so have a different exit relay? That helps, sometimes. Some sites just give CAPTCHAs to Tor users. And harder, even impossible, CAPTCHAs for exits that have recently given them lots of abuse. And some sites just block, instead of giving harder CAPTCHAs.

Some sites enable CloudFlare's option to access via a [CloudFlare onion service](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3050916/cloudflare-aims-to-block-fewer-legitimate-tor-users.html). But otherwise, if you want to use Tor for sites that block Tor exits, you'll need use a proxy with Tor.

If you use Whonix, you can run a VPN in the workstation VM. Tor browser will still use the Tor SocksProxy. But you can remove the SocksProxy setting from Firefox, and it will then connect through the VPN.

Everything in the Whonix workstation VM can only connect via Tor, including the VPN client, so there's no risk of leakage. But it's still far less anonymous than Tor, so it's something that you do when there's no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two reasons for it:

1. Java Script is restricted in your TOR browser
2. The site (or captcha provider) restrict TOR exit nodes.

For first cause, you can run TOR Browser and use another browser such as FireFox with proxy enabled inside FireFox. The proxy should point to TOR's socks proxy which is usually 127.0.0.1:9150. Here is a screen shot.
[image: FireFox Socks Proxy Configuration for using TOR]

For the second cause, unfortunately there is not a direct way for passing. I mean if Google banned TOR exit nodes, you cannot connect through them. But there is an indirect way: Using VPN through TOR which will change your exit IP (to the VPN's) but keep your main IP address private (through TOR). I've described it more in my blog:

- https://mstajbakhsh.ir/vpn-or-tor-this-is-the-problem/
- https://mstajbakhsh.ir/socks-rocks-again/
- https://mstajbakhsh.ir/socks-rocks-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/

[image: VPN or TOR]